# Nested list last row elements repeat through all the previous rows

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

I'm using the following code to input value to a nested list/matrix. But getting the identical row value assigned in the last row.

```py
rows = int(input('Input the rows: '))
cols = int(input('Input the cols: '))
#rows, cols = (5, 5) 
arr1 = [[int(0)]*cols]*rows
print(arr1) 
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        arr1[i][j]= int(input('arr1[%d][%d]: '%(i,j)))
        print(arr1[i][j])
print(arr1)
```

Let's

```py
>>> Input the rows: 2
>>> Input the cols: 2
```

Then,

```py
>>>rows
2
>>>cols
2
```

Afterwords,

```py
arr1[0][0]: 22
arr1[0][1]: 33
arr1[1][0]: 44
arr1[1][1]: 55
```

Lastly, the issue found. Last row elements repeat through all the previous rows.

```py
>>>print(arr1)
[[44, 55], [44, 55]]
```

It is also occurring for higher dimension matrices.

#### I don't want this to happen. Instead, I wish to get no repetition, like:

```py
>>>print(arr1)
[[22, 33], [44, 55]]
```

### Note : Using python 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: initialize multi-dimensional list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636567/python-initialize-multi-dimensional-list)

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem here:

```
arr1 = [[int(0)]*cols]*rows
```

Essentially, the `*` operator will create multiple references of the same object for mutable types.
One way to fix this is to use comprehensions (also the `int()` call in `int(0)` is useless, so I'll just skip it), e.g.:

```
arr1 = [[0 for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
```

or:

```
arr1 = [([0] * cols) for _ in range(rows)]
```

The inner `[0] * cols` would work as you expect because `0` is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

This peculiar functioning is because Python uses shallow lists which we will try to understand. if you look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/) you can find your answer.
Your **problem** is *in creating your nested list*.

```
arr1 = [[int(0)]*cols]*rows   <--- Here
```

And you can use this code instead of it:

```
arr1 = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in the code is the problem.
It would create bigger references.
You can make a blank list. `arr1 = []` and append like this. `arr1[i][j].append(int(input('arr1[%d][%d]: '%(i,j))))` Then the code would be easier to understand. and debuging is easier too.