# Why do the list function and list literals act differently?

Tags: python, list

I was trying to create a list with *n* empty lists inside of it, but faced an interesting situation.

Firstly I tried the following:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> list([]) * n
[]
```

It creates an empty list.

After that I tried the following line, which creates an empty list, too:

```
>>> list(list()) * n
[]
```

But when I try the same with literals,

```
>>> [[]] * n 
[[], [], []]
```

it gives the correct output. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Have you seen what `list(list())` compared to `[[]]`? Why do you *expect* these to work the same? Using the list constructor never works like a list literal

Comment: Note that `[[]] * n` likely *doesn't* give the correct output, as you'll find if you try to append to any of the inner lists - https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/3001761. `list([])` is the same as `list(list())`, because `list()` gives you an empty list `[]`.

Comment: As an aside, you almost certainly don't want to use `columns = [[]] * n` because this creates a list with `n` references *to the same empty list*

Comment: `[[]]` is not equal to `list(list())`

Comment: list() creates a list if no parameters are passed to it. If an iterable is passed to it, it returns a list with iterables items as values (think converting string or tuple). You can see then, if list() creates an empty list, a list([]) will return a list, containing values of an empty list, i.e. an empty list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`list(...)` is not interchangeable with `[...]`. You can wrap square brackets around things to get nested lists, but wrapping things in `list()` doesn't have the same effect.

- When you write `[[]]` you get a list with a single element. That element is `[]`.
- When you write `list([])` the `list` constructor takes an iterable and creates a list with the same elements. If you wrote `list(['foo', 'bar'])` the result would be `['foo', 'bar']`. Writing `list([])` yields `[]`.

  This form is more useful when you pass iterables that aren't lists. Other examples:

  ```
  list('abc') == ['a', 'b', 'c']         # strings are iterables over their characters
  list(('foo', 'bar')) == ['foo', 'bar'] # tuple
  list({'foo', 'bar'}) == ['foo', 'bar'] # set; could get ['bar', 'foo'] instead
  ```
- `list(list())` is equivalent to `list([])`. And we've seen that's in turn equivalent to `[]`.

Stay away from `[[]] * n` when creating a multidimensional list. It will create a list with `n` references to the *same list object* and will bite you when you try to modify the internal lists. It's a common mistake that everyone makes. Use this instead, which will create a *separate* empty list for each slot:

```
[[] for i in range(n)]
```

Further reading:

- [How to create a multi-dimensional list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636567/python-initialize-multi-dimensional-list)
- [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)